# Add user in minio with C#

Tags: c#, minio

I wanna add a user on MinIo with C# code but I do not understand what packages on NuGet Gallery are appropriate for this please help me for finding a package so that I can resolve my problem.

Comment: You could try to use the official SDK https://www.nuget.org/packages/Minio

Comment: tank you for answering but I wanna add a user and I can not find method for adding in this class. Could you tell me about this method

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The user management and Admin apis are not part of any s3 compatible minio SDKs.

there are 2 Solutions:

1. use: [madmin-go](https://github.com/minio/madmin-go) written in golang.
2. invoke the mc commands [mc](https://github.com/minio/mc) (like shell commands)